# How to use a global variable within a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, global-variables, shadowing

In section **Incorrectly matching against a variable** from [chapter 3](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html) of **real world haskell**, there is an example as follows:

```
-- file: ch03/BogusPattern.hs
data Fruit = Apple | Orange

apple = "apple"

orange = "orange"        

whichFruit :: String -> Fruit

whichFruit f = case f of
                 apple  -> Apple
                 orange -> Orange
```

The explanation says in `case f of` part, `apple` and `orange` are not treated as global variables as defined before the function declaration. They are local variables.I thought if there is no local variable owning the same name as a global variable, the global variable is not hidden.

Comment: "`apple` and `orange` are not treated as `String` type" that's not correct, nor does RWH claim it. Both the global and local `apple` have type `String`, it's just not _the same_ string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing here is that *variables in pattern matches always introduce new variables instead of referring to existing ones*. Your problem has nothing to do with global vs local variables.

If you want to match the value of `f` to the value of some variable like `apple` in a pattern you need to use pattern guards and equality tests. E.g.

```
whichFruit f
    | f == apple  = Apple
    | f == orange = Orange
```

Answer (score 1):

Right. But there is a local variable `apple` here owning the same name as the global variable `apple`, namely `apple` (duh).

The crucial thing about patterns is that they don't so much compare variables as *look out for specific distinguishing features*, while simultaneously re-packaging all other information into new variables. The "distinguishing features" are constructor matches (always uppercase<sup>1</sup>), which don't appear in `case f of { apple -> ... }`, so simply *all* the information is passed on in the variable `apple`.

### A more idiomatic example

```
data Vegetable = Tomato | Potato

data Edible = Fruit Fruit | Vegetable Vegetable
```

If you want a function to take an `Edible` argument, it's often useful to *deconstruct* the type. This might look thus:

```
canJuice :: Edible -> Bool
canJuice (Fruit Apple) = False
canJuice (Fruit Orange) = True
canJuice (Vegetable Tomato) = True
canJuice (Vegetable Potato) = False
```

Now, for more complicated data it's awkward to write such lots of `canJuice` clauses. An alternative would be to first match only on the outmost constructor, and delegate the further work elsewhere:

```
canJuice :: Edible -> Bool
canJuice (Fruit fruit) = fruitJuicy fruit
canJuice (Vegetable veg) = vegetableJuicy veg

vegetableJuicy :: Vegetable -> Bool
vegetableJuicy Tomato = True
vegetableJuicy Potato = False
```

For this to work, we needed Haskell's feature of treating any lowercase name appearing in a pattern as a new variable, which takes on the value in the "hole" of our pattern match.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are also infix constructors, the best-known is list-cons `(:)` (they all start with a colon, like all named constructors start uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

You have hit upon `irrefutable patterns`. As the book mentions, plain variable names and the wild card `_` are examples of irrefutable patterns. Another example which will demonstrate `irrefutable patterns` more clearly:

```
data Fruit = Apple | Orange deriving (Show)

patternMatch f = case f of
  something -> Apple
```

Now the above program typechecks with an warning. In ghci:

```
ghci> patternMatch 2
Apple
ghci> patternMatch "hi"
Apple
```

So basically the variable `something` is an irrefutable pattern which matches anything.

Now,coming back to your example:

```
whichFruit :: String -> Fruit
whichFruit f = case f of
                 apple  -> Apple
                 orange -> Orange
```

Here the variable `apple` and `orange` are irrefutable patterns. They doesn't refer to the global function which you have already created. In fact you can remove the global definition of `apple` and `orange` and compile them in order to get an idea. Whatever input you give, you will always get `Apple` as an answer for the above code (since it is an irrefutable pattern):

```
ghci > whichFruit "apple"
Apple
ghci > whichFruit "orange"
Apple
ghci > whichFruit "pineApple"
Apple
```

> How to use a global variable within a function in Haskell ?

That's pretty easy actually. Just use them in your function definition.

```
data Fruit = Apple | Orange deriving (Show)

apple = "apple"
orange = "orange"

giveFruit :: Fruit -> String
giveFruit Apple = apple
giveFruit Orange = orange
```

In ghci:

```
ghci> giveFruit Apple
"apple"
ghci> giveFruit Orange
"orange"
```

Using the variable in the function definition is straight forward.

---

> What should be done if I want the variable to refer to a global
>   variable owning the same name?

One way would be to use the entire module name to refer to it. Example:

```
module Fruit where

data Fruit = Apple | Orange deriving (Show)

apple = "apple"
orange = "orange"

giveFruit2 :: Fruit -> String
giveFruit2 apple = Fruit.apple
```

Comment: You mean whenever a new plain variable name appears in a function, a new variable is created? What should be done if I want the variable to refer to a global variable owning the same name?

Comment: @user811416: no no no. Whenever a variable name appears _in a pattern_, a new variable is created. (In fact, patterns are _the only_ places new variables can turn up.)

Comment: @user811416 Updated the answer. @leftaroundbot I think what the OP meant to say was whenever a new variable appears in the left side of the `=` in function definition. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Nor am I, but I don't think the OP was quite aware of the distinction between pattern code and expression code. Using a qualified module name is certainly not an appropriate way to "solve this problem".

Comment: @leftaroundabout I agree that the naming can be done more clearly. But in the above example (when both have the same name) I don't see any other way of solving this problem.